# Angular: is it a considered a good practice to have multiple services/factories in a services module?

Tags: angularjs

I would like to understand if it is a good practice to have more than one service factory in a f.e. `home.services.js` file which could have some other services inside.

**home.services.js** looks like this:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('fuelComparatorApp.homeServices', [])
        .service('sayHelloService', sayHelloService)
        .service('someService', someService);

    sayHelloService.$inject = ['$http', '$q'];
    someService.$inject = ['$http', '$q'];

    function someService() {
        const factory = {
            someMessageObject: [],
            someServiceMessage : someServiceMessage
        };

        function someServiceMessage() {
            factory.someMessageObject = {
                someMessageString: "Some message from someService.someServiceMessage"
            };
        }

        return factory;
    }

    function sayHelloService() {
        const factory = {
            //properties
            helloMessage: [],
            sayHi: sayHi,
            byeMessage: [],
            sayBye: sayBye
        };
        function sayHi(){
            factory.helloMessage =  {
                Message: "hello message from helloService!"
            };
        }

        function sayBye(){
            factory.byeMessage =  {
                Message: "bye message from helloService!"
            };
        }

        return factory;
    }
})();
```

Is this structure fine? Or is it only allowed to construct one factory / per `*.service.js` which could include multiple services/functions inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is much better to have each service in its own file and name the file same as the service. By this way, you will be able to use "open resource" shortcut in your favorite IDE/editor to find a service's code. This is more practical than text search in files when your codebase goes larger.

Comment: So that means it is better to just inject services from separate `.js` files which are going to be used by `home.services.js` and later use them inside a f.e. `controller`?

Comment: Yes. When you put the services under the same Angular module, you can inject these services into other services or controllers, directives, filters etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer and replies!